# New Zealand Residence Visa under SMC

Tags: immigration, new-zealand

Can I apply New Zealand Residence Visa under SMC? I am married and have two kids. I want to apply Residence only for me. If I get RV, then I would like to initiate RV for my family. Is it possible? Without my wife's points, I am getting 165 points

Comment: Why would you not include your wife and kids in your application?

Comment: https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/skilled-migrant-category-resident-visa

Comment: Because most of the times, applicants are getting JSV(job search visa) even though if you have paid for whole family. With JSV, only I can travel, not my family. Seems reasonable to me to apply only for me, then after getting job, apply for whole family.